# How to limit access to wp-admin in case of a dynamic IP address?

Tags: wordpress

I have dynamic IP address and I am trying to find the solution to limit the access to wp-admin. It seems that the only option is to block the access by domain name by using a Dynamic DNS Manager instead of IP address. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What has the dynamic IP? The client or the server?

Comment: I have dynamic IP address and I would like to limit access to wp-admin. The website is hosted on shared server.

Comment: "I have" -- my question is who the "I" is. The server or the client?

Answer (score 1):

What about using client certificates for the particular URI?

eg: Access to `https://example.com/` is allowed, but for `https://example.com/wp-admin` the client needs to provide a valid certificate.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate

Comment: You can also use a basic HTTP authentication for this location.

Comment: Thats true, but most people would use the same as the wp admin password, so when you got one you can login to wp.